# React (CRA) disable typescript check globally

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a migration of a react project and didn't find a way of disabling typescript globally. It works well with @ts-nocheck on top of each file that I need, but I would like to know if there is something easier than that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit your `tsconfig.json` file with something similar to:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "alwaysStrict": false,
      "strict": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noEmitOnError": false,
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
      "noImplicitReturns": false,
      "noImplicitThis": false
  },
  "include": [
      "src/*"
  ],
}
```

This doesn't disable it, but it's like it doesn't exists.